# Where do gradle unit tests for Google app engine expect persistence.xml?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, junit, gradle

I have created a Google app engine project using an maven archetype project with the Datanucleus JPA provider, essentially following the Google app engine documentation.

Everything works fine when running the maven goal "test".

Now I had to integrate the project into Android studio and wanted to migrate the build script to gradle. I copied all dependencies from the `pom.xml` to the `build.gradle` and the project builds fine. However, all tests that access the Google datastore fail.

During test output I get the following message:

> Warning:No META-INF/persistence.xml files were found in the CLASSPATH of the current thread!

I checked the `build` folder which is created during the build and no folder contains the `persistence.xml` from `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF`

Using maven, however, it is correctly put in the `target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` folder.

I have tried copying the `persistence.xml` using a gradle copy task into various locations, such as `build/classes/META-INF` `build/classes/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` and so on, but nothing worked.

Comment: While I certainly do not know enough about gradle, etc. to definitively answer this, the almighty Goog has given me [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279060/jpa-with-toplink-no-meta-inf-persistence-xml-was-found-in-classpath) which may help.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. However, my project is building the WAR fine. The persistence.xml is correctly put into the WEB-INF/classes/META-INF folder. This is not the issue. The issue is that when running the unit tests (where no WAR is being build), the persistence.xml has to be put *somewhere*. I am asking for this somewhere.

Comment: my approach would be to put 1 in each folder until it runs :) that seems lame but has proven to be effective

Comment: @deW1 you can literally put them everywhere and do a binary search…

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397336/no-persistence-providers-available-for-transactions-optional-after-trying-the

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just because the file is placed in a directory doesn't automatically mean it's in the CLASSPATH.

Place the META-INF folder containing `persistence.xml` in `/src/main/resources`.

Comment: This is actually correct. Thank you a thousand times. But can you maybe elaborate a bit further, why Gradle build expects the file under `resources` when web files should go under `webapp`?

Comment: He probably would, if he hadn't *(most likely)* copied his answer without knowing what it meant from a comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15403627/4686625), from the question Travis J linked.

Comment: check out this answer for more info about how mvn rearranges things

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297473/maven-including-a-meta-inf-folder-in-the-classes-folder

Comment: As the link skullkid posted says, Maven has the convention that all non-source files for source set `main` should go into `src/main/resources`. Gradle follows that Maven convention, unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: I do not want to stress this any further, but Maven builds fine with the file placed under webapp and Gradle does not. Of course, this could mean that Gradle follows Maven conventions stricter than Maven itself.